# Uploading to AWS S3 bucket from a profile in a different environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have access to one of two AWS environments and I've created a protected S3 bucket in it to upload files to from an account in the one that I do not. The environment and the account that I don't have access to are what a project's CI uses.

- environment I have access to: `env1`
- environment I do not have access to: `env2`
- account I do not have access to: `user/ci`
- bucket name: `content`

S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access to bucket from profile in env1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/ci"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::content"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access to bucket items from profile in env1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/ci"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::content",
                "arn:aws:s3:::content/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From inside a container that's configured for `env1` and `user/ci` I'm testing with the command

```
aws s3 sync content/ s3://content/
```

and I get the error:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I have two questions:

1. Am I even using the correct `aws` command to upload the data to the bucket?
2. Am I missing something from my bucket policy?

For the latter, I've basically followed what a load of examples and answers online have suggested.

Comment: What happens if you try `aws s3 ls s3://content/` as `user/ci`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I get the same error as when I try to `sync`

Comment: Then whatever credentials you are using do not have the required permissions. If you run `aws iam get-user`, does it say that you are `user/ci`?

Comment: it actually says that `user/ci` is not authorized to perform `iam:GetUser on resource: user ci`, but it is giving the correct account ID and user name as the one attempting the call

Answer (score 0):

To test your policy, I did the following:

- Created an IAM User with *no policies*
- Created an Amazon S3 bucket
- Attached your Bucket Policy to the bucket, and updated the ARN and bucket name
- Tested access to the bucket with:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname

aws s3 sync folder/ s3://bucketname/folder/
```

It worked fine.

Therefore, the policy you display appears to be giving all necessary permissions. It is possible that you have something else that is Denying access on the bucket.

Comment: It's not clear by the answer if you used two accounts. Was the account that you created and added in the policy in a different account than the one that the bucket lives in?

Comment: Ah! If you used two separate accounts then the user in the account _without_ the bucket also requires permissions on their IAM User that permits them to use the bucket in the other account (or general `s3:*` permissions, but that's not good for security). Basically, the user needs permission to call S3, and the bucket needs to permit their access. This is a special situation when using multiple accounts. Does the `ci` IAM User have any S3 permissions?

Comment: That's what it ended up fixing it. The IAM User in the other environment needed to be given an ACL policy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to given the ACL

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"      
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::content",
                "arn:aws:s3:::content/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

to `user/ci` in `env1`.